# Where am I supposed to ask a question about recommending a platform to code on?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to ask a “Recommended design / tool for the job” question correctly, and where?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147641/how-to-ask-a-recommended-design-tool-for-the-job-question-correctly-and-whe)

I want to discuss possible platforms to code projects on (Java Swing versus web development with Rails or flash or... etc.) given some requirements, but I'm not sure where on stackoverflow I should ask that... here, in meta, or in regular stackoverflow, or some other stackexchange place? There's so many...

Comment: Not on any, I don't think shopping questions are on topic on any of the programming-related sites.

Comment: One of the reasons Stack Exchange is such a great platform for asking specific, practical questions is that more 'open-ended', discussion/opinion type questions are not on-topic here.